# SSH Remote Debug Profile using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssh

I am using Visual Studio to debug via SSH code deployed onto an embedded device.

Currently my workflow is

1. Publish
2. Copy to Device
3. Visual Studio -> Attach Remote Debugger via SSH

However I want to automate all these steps, and just click the Green Debug button to achieve the same thing.

Although I have setup SSH in connection manager, and it works via Attach Remote Debugger, there is no SSH options available in Launch Profiles:

[image]

I am aware this is possible in VSCode, however I want to use Visual Studio.